# Replacing connection string with a method in factory pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, factory, enterprise-library

I am planning to replace the factory created connection string which is from web.config with a function generated connection string. I am confused where to make this change?

Connection String in Web config as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionStringToDB" connectionString="Data Source=GTD,2431;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=WorkflowExecutionDB;User ID=Dev_FID;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
  </connectionStrings>
```

Currently following code will call this above connection string:

```
  DatabaseProviderFactory factory;            /* enterprise data library*/
  Database ConnectionStringToDB;             /* database schema*/
  factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
  // Create a Database object from the factory using the connection string name.
  ConnectionStringToDB = factory.Create("ConnectionStringToDB");
  DbCommand dbCmd = ConnectionStringToDB.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_Name");
```

Suppose i need to change the connection string which is coming from web-config to function method result as like below, where i need to put the GetConnectionString() in the code? :

```
 public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
      return "Data Source=GTD,2431;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=WorkflowExecutionDB;User ID=Dev_FID;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"     
     }
```

Following might be wrong:

```
ConnectionStringToDB = factory.Create(GetConnectionString());
```

What the is the right way?

Comment: You should post the factory too. I assume the factory is using the `string` parameter to access the resource to get the value which is the actual connection string. If the parameter is the key, then you'd have to replace the web config access with an invokation of the new `GetConnectionString()` method. Then remove the `string` parameter from the `Create`method. The factory usage would become: `ConnectionStringToDB = factory.Create();`

Comment: @BionicCode the factory is [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb746639(v=pandp.31)) -- so one does not simply remove the `string` parameter from `Create`.